# For loop in Jinja2/python not working (using sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have the following for loop in jinja:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <td>Stock</td>
       <td>Shares</td>
       <td>Total</td>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       {% for dict in rows2 %}
       <tr>
           {% for key, value in dict.items() %}
           <td> {{value}} </td>
           {% endfor %}
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

which gets the data from my flask app, particularly from the following line:

```
rows2 = db.execute("SELECT stock, amount, total_value FROM portfolio WHERE id = :id", id = session.get("user_id"))
```

Now, if I print rows2 to console, I actually get what I want, that is something like this:

```
[{'stock': 'AAPL', 'amount': 1, 'total_value': 676.4}, {'stock': 'BB', 'amount': 1, 'total_value': 10.53}, {'stock': 'IBM', 'amount': 1, 'total_value': 144.99}]
```

but the table in the webpage only shows the header part and the actual data part is left blank! Why could this be?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you passing `rows2` correctly to the render-call?

Comment: I guess so?     return render_template("portfolio.html") where portfolio is the file where the table is.

Comment: Post the code as how you are rendering the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think the culprit is in your call to `render_template()`. You not only need to pass the template name, but also **the variables used in the template**. [See here for the flask-docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

So you should actually be doing

```
return render_template("portfolio.html", rows2=rows2)
```

... where the left-hand-side is the name in the template, and the right-hand-side is the variable you assigned to in your logic.

Comment: @JustABeginner, I completely changed my answer based on your comment regarding rendering. Does this help?

Comment: yayyy!!! it works! :D thanks you!!! I had no idea I had to pass the parameters, it seemed kind of redundant since the variable rows2 was already in the part of the app that covers the "main page" route!

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the () after items():

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: tried this, unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be displaying any data :/